# Issue with javascript option

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have an issue with a javascript, by default hide option of a select and when value match will popup. Problem is when try to match second value, wont work. Any ideas ? Code and demo bellow.
Thank you.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  /* jshint browser: true */

  var d = document;
  var mf = d.getElementById('myform');
  var se = d.getElementById('second');
  var tr = d.getElementById('third');
  var lo = d.getElementById('location')
  var temp;
  mf.reset();
  se.className = 'hide';
  tr.className = 'hide';
  lo.onchange = function() {
    if (this.value === 'act_aditional_onorariu') {
      se.className = se.className.replace('hide', '');
    } else {
      temp = this.value;
      se.className = 'hide';
      mf.reset();
      lo.value = temp;
    }
  };

}());
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <select name="tip_document" size="1" style="font-size:12pt;" id="location">
    <option value="" selected>Selectati un document</option>
    <option value="act_aditional">Act aditional</option>
    <option value="act_aditional_onorariu">Act aditional (majorare onorariu)</option>
    <option value="act_reziliere">Reziliere contract</option>
    <option value="modificare_salvare">Modificare contract (salvari)</option>
    <option value="modificare_contract">Modificare contract (draft)</option>
  </select>
  <p id="second">
    <font style="color:green"><b>Suma act aditional 1</b></font>
    <input type="text" name="suma_act_aditional" value="0" style="font-size:13pt; width: 63px;" onkeypress="return [46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57].includes(event.charCode);"> <b>RON</b>
  </p>
  <p id="third">
    <font style="color:green"><b>Suma act aditional 2</b></font>
    <input type="text" name="suma_act_aditional" value="0" style="font-size:13pt; width: 63px;" onkeypress="return [46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57].includes(event.charCode);"> <b>RON</b>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: In this case please post an example of final HTML, not PHP source. And try to create a [mre] using the `<>` button. (also, you can change which classes an element has using `.classList.add()` and `.classList.remove()`

Comment: `try to match second value` - your code does not

Comment: so you want to show `id="second"` when selecting a specific option and then hide what ? or show what ? You never check for a second value ( for the #third `p` element )  also you have some deprecated elements like `<font>` . also your `myform` is undefined.

Comment: I have created a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992) with your code. Things I have changed: 1) Added a `form` wrapper with `id="myform"` 2) Added a `hide` class 3) Removed the php part as it seems irrelevant here. If any of these assumptions are wrong please update the snippet